# How to get a variable fieldname?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a record called `ouderecord` I get from a table with a SQL statement.

I have this code:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT * from tblS1lijst where id = " & Keuzelijst3.Column(0)
Debug.Print strSQL
ouderecord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Tmpstr = Mid(Keuzelijst3.Column(2), InStr(1, Keuzelijst3.Column(2), ".") + 1, _
  Len(Keuzelijst3.Column(2)) - InStr(1, Keuzelijst3.Column(2), ".") - 1)
veld_naam = "[" & Tmpstr & "]"
tekst = "ouderecord!" & veld_naam
Debug.Print tekst
```

When I hover over the text (`ouderecord![Situatie]`) in the Direct window, I see the contents of the field. How do I get that content in a variable?

I want "Situatie" as a variable.

Comment: `Dim s As String` / `s = ouderecord![Situatie]` where `s` must have the correct type.

Comment: But I want to have "Situatie" as a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of the field is static, you can do it like this

```vb
Dim tekst As String

tekst = Nz(ouderecord![Situatie])
```

or

```vb
tekst = Nz(ouderecord!Situatie)
```

The `[` and `]` are only required if the column name contains invalid characters like a space character or a hyphen or if it conflicts with a keyword.

But if the name is given dynamically in a variable, you must access the `Fields` default property of the `Recordset`

```vb
tekst = Nz(ouderecord(veld_naam))
```

This is the same as

```vb
tekst = Nz(ouderecord.Fields(veld_naam).Value)
```

Where `veld_naam` must be the name of the field without the column name escapes `[` and `]`: E.g.,  `veld_naam = "Situatie"`

Note that the parameter can be either a String representing the name of the field or an Integer representing the index of the column in the query.

The `Nz` function converts NULL values into and appropriate value for the given type. In this case it returns an empty string for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

That Nz did the trick!
I now have

```
strSQL = "SELECT * from tblS1lijst where id = " & Keuzelijst3.Column(0)
Debug.Print strSQL
ouderecord = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
Tmpstr = Mid(Keuzelijst3.Column(2), InStr(1, Keuzelijst3.Column(2), ".") + 1, Len(Keuzelijst3.Column(2)) - InStr(1, Keuzelijst3.Column(2), ".") - 1)
veld_naam = "[" & Tmpstr & "]"
tekst = "ouderecord!" & veld_naam
tekst = Nz(ouderecord(veld_naam))

Debug.Print tekst
```

And that works.

Comment: You can drop the line `tekst = "ouderecord!" & veld_naam`. Also the field name must be without `[` and `]` now. `veld_naam = Tmpstr`

Comment: Can I drop the [ and ] even if there is a space in the fieldname?

Comment: If you pass it directly like `rs![The name]` you must keep them as it would not compile, because VBA would not know where the name ends. VBA assumes that it ends at the space. Note that `[` `]` are only delimiters and that they are not part of the name. Therefore they must not be contained in the name variable: `veld_naam = "The name": tekst = rs(veld_naam)`

Comment: unbelievable how fast you get your head around this. I simplified the code and dropped the temporary string and the []..  Now for the rest...